# Will people use Stack Overflow less often if the information found there isn't 100% accurate?

Tags: discussion, old-questions, old-answers, outdated-information

I needed to take some time to explain what I'm lately experiencing while using Stack Overflow to find possible solutions to problems I'm facing while working. It's happening more and more often that I need to implement a generic task or patch a possible security issue, so I'm searching for answers and ideas in Stack Overflow, sure that I'll find something I need.

The problem is when I actually find the answers to the problem I'm having: they are (most of the time) outdated and referring to very old libraries, implementation methods or security patches that are not secure anymore. This is quite frustrating, because I have possible working answers in front of me, but not being aware and super-expert of all topics in my field, sometimes I need to trust other people's advice and, in Stack Overflow's case, correct upvoted answers. But when the correct, upvoted answer was written in, for example, 2002, what I actually do is taking some additional time to find and read the actual documentation or security methodologies from updated sources.

An additional issue caused by the outdated answers is having more and more duplicate questions posted by new and also old OPs. I'm often on the "newest questions" page in Stack Overflow and I can say that a lot of them have a duplicate already, but I may understand why people post them: they can't actually find help from already existing answers, because they are (sometimes, not always, just to be clear) really outdated and refer to libraries and methods not in use anymore by the software development world.

I'm new to Stack Overflow Meta and I don't feel really comfortable asking directly for a new feature, that's why I just wanted to start a discussion about this. I think it would make sense to notify owners of old, accepted and/or most upvoted answers to take some time to take a look to their answers and update them with the most recent solution, giving them also the possibility to set the answer as "not anymore up-to-date", letting other users to provide the newest solutions. The new solution would be set as valid by the old valid answer owner. My opinion would be that the rep wouldn't decrease for the old valid answer owner.

My overall doubt is that in the future people will use Stack Overflow less and less if the information found here isn't be 100% accurate as usually expected.

I've been reading all the other questions related to this issue, but always the discussion was on how to behave with old upvoted answers, rep points and stuff like that, not talking about the actual accuracy of answers 10 or even more years after they were posted.

Comment: @yivi, thank you, I edited my question explaining that I just wanted to start a discussion about the feature request I'm talking about, I'm new here, so I'm not sure I can just ask for a new feature without first having a discussion about it, reading other people's ideas and thoughts... By the way, the question would be "Will in the future less and less people use SO if the information there won't be 100% accurate?" :)

Comment: You can ask for a FR. Just use the tag "feature-request" instead of "discussion". Read the [tag guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info) about how to go about creating a feature-request and what's required from such a question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for fixing my post and the tags, I would like to keep this post on a discussion level only, for now. I'd like to know what other people think about this and if it is an actual shared problem other people have, if it makes then sense for me to prepare a feature request post with all the discussed details.

Comment: 'notify owners of old, accepted and/or most upvoted answers to take some time to take a look to their answers and update them with the most recent solution' - you can do that - add your own answer, updated to the latest version/s of whatever, making it plain what you are doing..  No need to nag users to keep their 'perfectly good at the time' answers up-to-date.  There was a question, they answered it, they got some rep and an accept - done.

Comment: '100% accurate' well, with a  moveable feast such as you describe, that's not going to be achievable.  Just get closer to that 100 - answer with you own stuff and 'Updated to use gungelib V2.4' :)

Comment: I've probably got some outdated answers in the angular tag but I'm not touching angular again with a 10 foot pole no matter how many notifications I get so feel free to fix them for me :)

Comment: I would use as examples some old security patches (think about stuff checked by OWASP ZAP, for example), if you google for each of the vulnerabilities checked by OWASP, you can find answers posted in Stack Overflow that still reflect the situation we had in 2010...

Comment: @ivarni, that's why I was thinking on something that could let old answers' owners to re-open (somehow) the question, letting other people answering with the most updated way to solve the issue. I was also used to work with GIS and post quite a lot in the related Stack Exchange website, but I wouldn't have any idea right now how to answer questions I've answered with up-to-date methods.

Comment: Well, the thing is, you are expecting the users who answered the old questions to undertake a round of update, design, code, test, debug, verify that is likely of no immediate use to them.  I cannot imagine that many users would be willing to do that, in fact, I suspect that any reply to such a request would be less than CoC worthy.

Comment: @MartinJames, no, I'm not expecting anyone to do so, I've also explained it again in my last comment (answering to ivarni). I would let answer owners  update their answer OR re-open it to let other people answer with the up-to-date solution.

Comment: @Alberto sorry, I misunderstand?  The old questions to which you refer are closed?

Comment: Why would the question-askers want to go through that process again just to get a new answer to some problem they had years ago in a codebase they might not even have access to anymore? I'd say the same argument applies to questions as answers. We just can't expect the original people involved in a Q&A to keep going back to their old content to fix it. We need the people who are facing those issues today to post better answers if the ones we have are outdated.

Comment: @ivarni, "We need the people who are facing those issues today to post better answers if the ones we have are outdated" yes exactly, the problem here is that we will still have the old outdated answers marked as valid. My only thoughts go to the future users that won't find the outdated valid answers useful and will try to find their answers outside Stack Overflow.

Comment: @OrangeDog, sure, but most of the times I'm on Stack Overflow looking for better implementations or "best practices" on how to implement a solution to a task or bug I'm working on, never just to find the valid answer and copy/paste it, of course.

Comment: Most of the problems with outdated posts can be solved by editing that post. SO is explicitly partly Wiki, so that kind of thing is possible. Of course, that requires that somebody knowledgable finds that outdated post and has both the skills and necessary reputation to edit that post. We may or may not need some technical mechanism to surface such posts to the right people. A second buried point here is that the number of duplicates keeps increasing, which paradoxically doesn't necessarily make it easier to find duplicates. This may indeed need some serious solution.

Comment: @deceze, thank you, this is exactly what made me write this post. "We may or may not need some technical mechanism to surface such posts to the right people", I think that experienced SO users wouldn't be so unhappy to keep the knowledge up to date, even if they wouldn't be able to do it on their own, but asking for help (aka, letting other people answer and setting their answer as valid).

Comment: @Alberto I disagree. Maintenance of old questions is not a realistic activity for experienced SO users.  They put in their effort once, and provided a tested solution using 'gungelib V1.5'.  If someone is kind enough to provide and edit that adds to the question/answer, saying 'here is an updated version using gungelib V2.4', then it's an edit like any other.  Same with a completely new answer with the appropriate info about the library version used.  It should not involve the original 'V1.5' answerer at all, and their orignal answer should be left as-is and only supplemented.

Comment: 'The new solution would be set as valid by the old valid answer owner' no, no.  They would have to test it!  No!

Comment: @Alberto Some food for thought: I have only a few hundred answers, and I don't manage to keep them all up to date. Some I just don't care enough about. Many involve platforms that I don't always reliably have the *ability* to test on without spinning up a (probably illegal) VM - sometimes I have a Mac or a Windows box to hand to test something involving iOS or .NET, but sometimes I don't; it varies as my personal and employment circumstances change. Some of my answers are about paid cloud services my ex-employers paid for which I can no longer access and don't want to spend personal money on.

Comment: @Alberto ... and some people have *tens of thousands* of answers. You can't reasonably expect people to remain forever invested in such a huge number of questions and be ever ready to review new answers and pass the green checkmark. I'm sympathetic to the idea that keeping accepted answers forever pinned to the top of the answer list is unhelpful since such answers are regularly not the best answer in a thread, but I think the right solution to *that* is to unprivilege the green checkmark and have a better default way of determining answer sort order.

Comment: Thank you all, @StephenLeppik I'm sorry, I've removed the feature-request tag and restored the discussion one because I'm not presenting anything that could be actually used to even start defining a feature. Mark Amery thanks, you're absolutely right. This could lead to an algorithm that checks for very old answers with a certain number of upvotes, showing them in a standard view (as we have now "my tags", "newest", etc), something like "review needed". This could also lead to new badges and ways to increase rep.

Comment: @Alberto probably just a new review queue, although I think we have too many of those already.

Comment: @StephenLeppik, I would maybe see it as an easy way to increase rep and get badges. Think about the users that play the "fastest gun in the West" to try to answer the newest questions to get rep points. If you have a new public list with all these super-old valid answers that MAY need review, you can have people actually reviewing and setting them as "in need of new answer", then other people spending time answering with the updated solution...

Comment: Yup, sounds like a review queue to me.

Comment: Yes, as per definition, *it is*; what I would think of is to open it up to users with less than 500/2k/3k rep points (https://stackoverflow.com/review), allowing also new users (maybe only from 100 rep, just to say) to access this new review queue and help improving the answers quality.

Comment: SO was launched in 2008. If you're seeing an answer from 2002, something is very wrong indeed.

Comment: I do not know if someone trully expects anything (whatever it might be) to be 100% accurate.

Comment: So you expect someone like Jon Skeet (who literally has thousands of answers) to monitor them to see if something changes and keep them updated to the most modern solution to the problem, and expect every user here who has ever accepted an answer to monitor those posts to see if a newer, updated answer has been posted and possibly punish the person who originally answered them by removing the accept (deducting the 15 points they received) and having those points transferred elsewhere (even though that original post was correctly and accurately accepted at the time it was written)? Sounds wrong

Comment: 2002? Do you mean 2012? Stack Overflow (private beta) was launched in August 2008.

Comment: Re *... notify owners of old, accepted and/or most upvoted answers to take some time to take a look to their answers and update them with the most recent solution*: That won't fly as there is no quick rep to be had.

Comment: Simple, allow users to mark an answer as deprecated or outdated or unsecure. Don't remove the answer, but just add a label "deprecated".

Comment: Related: [old question review queue suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257131/215485)

Comment: @KenWhite - to be fair if there was _anyone_ I would expect to be able to do it it would be Jon Skeet. Although I heard Jon Skeet's answers never go out of date as the software changes to match his answers...

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland: Possibly. :-) But there are literally millions of users who have posted answers here in considerable numbers, and expecting them to do all the labor of trying to keep them current is unreasonable (not to mention it might invalidate them as an answer to the question actually asked, and also breaks it for people who are still using the old technology for some reason - there are people who seek info about Win95 and the Win32 API, and breaking all the old API posts by updating them to new code would kill all the answers to their posts they would find in searches normally).

Comment: @KenWhite - I hear you brother. I routinely have to work with Classic ASP and already resources for that are getting scarce.

Comment: 46 upvotes for 'everyone should ensure that their old Q&A are kept up-to-date by continually rebuilding and retesting their own, and others' new contributions, just to move some old rep around'?  Have meta contributors finally lost all touch with reality?

Comment: I agree this is an issue. I frequently encounters new issues that have the same symptoms than a very old major issue... But that have nothing else in common (cause or solution). The new questions/answers are very difficult to find. I would make great use of an option "ignore post > 2 years old", which would ideally percolate to Google search results

Comment: @MarkAmery _"and some people have tens of thousands of answers. You can't reasonably expect people to remain forever invested..."_ Was going to comment that. I agree 100%. Even [Jon Skeet couldn't do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974922/how-do-i-safely-cast-a-system-object-to-a-bool-in-c/1974969#comment91256455_1974969) :-D

Comment: Its really simple, if it is outdated, update it. If the answer is useful it will rise to the top over time.

Comment: Are you a fan of [Stack Sort](https://gkoberger.github.io/stacksort/) too? <more serious> You should never blindly copy and paste an answer (read: you should never blindly run code from the internet).

Comment: By personal experience I can tell you that I no longer visit stack overflow first.

This because in the last 2 years quality of Accepted answers has decreased and thread redirect is being abused IMHO.

Comment: Referenced in meta post *[Introducing Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302)* (2021-02-18).

Answer (score 42):

Your main issue here is:

> You cannot copy random code from the internet and expect it to match your needs

I know C/C++ and Python well enough, so when I search on the site, I know which answers are good and which aren't, what I want to use and what I don't. The answer score gives a good indication but it may not answer *your* question.

Besides, comments below the answers tend to "correct" a very highly voted answer if it's outdated. Don't focus on the most upvoted answer (specially for the old answers), read all upvoted answers and make up your mind. But for that you need a minimum of knowledge in the field because *Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site, it's a Q&A site*

You can already "correct" answers you find outdated by downvoting, or suggest edits for future readers (ex: the Python 3 version is xxxxx).

Get more rep/badges and you'll be able to edit without review, close questions as duplicates to link them to some better "originals": the search will be easier for future users. With more rep, you'll be able to vote to delete bad answers that clutter the site (unless you have the "chance" to still see them in purple with 10k :))

Let's say I want to learn R. I'll search for stuff and will read answers I don't understand. I may even not be able to make it work on my machine because I don't know the basics.

(un)fortunately, learning a subject cannot be done only by asking questions to google.

Comment: You are only talking about specific technical topics. I'm talking about everything is now present in SO, including security measures, best practices, etc. Nobody just copy/paste from SO.

Comment: This is not the main issue: *You cannot copy random code from the internet and expect it to match your needs*. This is not even *the* issue :)

Comment: I hear there are editor plugins that copy/paste code from SO for you. This is a very common dev behaviour.

Comment: @Alberto "Nobody just copy/paste from SO" Lol

Comment: To be fair, security measures and best practices are _off-topic_ so that's kind of irrelevant. SO is about code.

Comment: TBH, the entire question reads like 'everyone else should put in a massive, continual re-evaluation and retesting effort so that copy/pasted code has a better chance of working today with minimal extra effort on my part'.  @Alberto that may not be what you intended to convey, but that's how it looks:(

Comment: @Alberto you're sarcastic right? Code gets copy/pasted all the time!

Comment: Ok, let's make it clear: my original post wasn't about copy/pasting code. I understand that there are **a lot** of newbies that try to be lucky by just copy/pasting the code in their functions. But this is not the issue in my original post. I'm discussing about old outdated answers that may confuse new users and letting them look for answers somewhere outside SO.

Comment: @Alberto I don't think we need to be borderline condescending towards novices either. I copy/paste code from here too.

Comment: I copy paste code from here as well. Well, sometimes I paste code _to_ stackoverflow for a change :)

Comment: "read all upvoted answers" I would rather say read *several* upvoted answers.

Comment: True, but well, unless there are 7 pages of "how to convert int to float", I try to read all of them, to correct/downvote some wrongly upvoted "try this link" ones...

Comment: I generally don't venture beyond the top 4 or 5, unless I can see they won't work for my use case or something. And even then, I try to skip ones that don't seem promising. I can't read that fast. =) So I've had to adapt.

Answer (score 38):

As a fairly new user and contributor on SO, I understand @Alberto's main point: There is an amount of older content, (edit: not all but some), that each year becomes less relevant and reliable, and this issue is often seen in the top/accepted answers.

This issue will increase with time. It is well to consider how we might fairly and reasonably address the current situation in which (sometimes) more current, more secure, mo' better solutions are relegated to 2nd, 5th, or lower positions simply by virtue of their recency.

In the newspaper business, "above the fold" refers to the placement of the most salient/interesting/important news on the top half of the page, the part of the page that readers see first before they unfold the paper. Less important news follows "below the fold" and on the inside pages. Everyone will read the top headline; few will read page 5.

One purpose of upvotes on SO is to help ensure that the most relevant advice appears 
"above the fold." If that purpose is no longer being adequately facilitated by upvotes, expert feedback, and other features of the SO model, changes of some kind may be needed.

One idea: user option to sort results by a **combination of relevance and recency**. (Perhaps this is already part of the algorithm.)

Another idea: Make **the YEAR in which answers were submitted or edited** a more prominent visual feature to viewers.

The promise of the SO format is that the cream rises to the top. We let the cream rise so it can be separated and used in making butter and yogurt. As one who churned the family butter (and listened to some Devo) in my youth, do not let the cream sit out too long. You have to skim it (and whip it) before it sours!

Comment: Your cream analogy is good for some situations, but sours for others. While you can never guarantee that technical issues will always be true, even such quality pieces as the branch prediction answer, these will certainly be true for a decently long amount of time; on the other hand, there is a guarantee that cream will go bad in a relatively short amount of time. So, I don't think that it holds true that material here goes bad as quickly as the analogy implies.

Comment: That said, your "above the fold" analogy is fairly spot on, and important to the site to maintain as a goal where possible. However, while it is true that there are certain cases where newer answers are the better and more relevant ones which have not "bubbled up", it is far from the norm, and not that common. Using a "combination of relevance and recency" was part of the goal of the hot questions list, but the type of implementation used lends itself to be weighted far more for recency.

Comment: I agree. The cream analogy is imperfect and I didn't mean to imply that spoilage is inevitable in a day or even a year. Some answers are still relevant a decade on. I edited my first paragraph to be clear that only some, not all, of older content becomes less relevant.

Comment: Perhaps newer upvotes could count for more in the sorting algorithm than old votes? This would keep old but still relevant answers at the top while speeding the rise of answers that are currently more helpful/relevant

Comment: An interesting idea, @divibisan. New answers, more likely pertaining to newer libraries/releases/issues, and presumably what most current searches are seeking, would be rewarded by a bump in their weighting. If wisely implemented, those who provide these answers (and those who hunt deeper on the page to find these answers) would also be rewarded without unfairly pushing answers from 2012 too far down the page. Note, however: New upvotes, now weighted, for old answers, could even more firmly cement some old answers at the top. That's not necessarily a bad thing, just something to consider.

Comment: Note: when I say some content becomes "less relevant," I don't mean it's not useful to some users. It's extremely relevant if that's what you're looking for! I mean it probably isn't a "hit" for searches at the "modes." It's less relevant "on average." The point, I think, is to consider what is relevant to some plurality of today's users. That target changes as the years go by. The answers more commonly sought by a particular search term should be more easily findable, ideally "above the fold." Content less commonly sought can be "below the fold," still findable but not the top headline.

Comment: My proposed solution: stop pinning the accepted answer after about two or three years. If the accepted answer hasn't got the most upvotes even after its privileged position for two or three years, it doesn't deserve to be at the top. Maybe it can be pinned to second position.

Comment: @Flimm, great point. Sometimes answers are accepted quickly as a way for the OP to indicate that they found a solution that worked for them. They don't necessarily notice or change their acceptance if a better answer is posted the next day/week/year because they have moved on to other things and are no longer "moderating" the topic. If later answers receive more upvotes it makes sense at some point, a year or two later, to raise it to the top spot because the upvotes demonstrate its greater relevance.

Answer (score 25):

There's two ways we don't currently have a good way of deprecating content on Stack Overflow:

- In answers (e.g. oldest, accepted, highly-upvoted answer says "just use MD5 and store the hash in your database" for a question about creating user accounts in PHP).
- With *questions* overall - at some point results can become things you trip over or step on.

I don't have *good* answers for both, especially the second, because it entails keeping an orchestra running between new and established content and Google / etc crawlers. We know we show up fast in indexes, but experiments where we actually try to selectively decay in indexes *are pretty gosh darn dangerous* given that we're playing with the spoon that feeds us. We should treat that as a separate problem, because it doesn't prevent us from working on the first.

I want to revisit how we handle answers that just need to go off into the sunset, and I'd like to get to that at the end of this year or at the beginning of next year. Telling people "just edit" doesn't work when it's an accepted answer and needs to be rewritten completely, that steps on collaborative convention too much. All other options draw folks *very* passionately in favor or against them, but this is something we're going to need to work out.

But is it a *huge* problem across the site, where 'across the site' could be defined as all tags that go into awarding a generalist badge at any given time? No, not *particularly*. It's exacerbated quite a bit when the topic focus is on security or efficiency especially with fast-moving frameworks, but we're not in any immediate danger.

However, yeah, the time to think about these things is *ideally* before they become urgent; I've personally been poking around this for the better part of four years now, so I think we definitely have to settle on a plan. But, as others said (summarized): *you gotta know what you're looking at, look thoroughly, and don't blindly copy / paste code you found on the internet.*

I'll leave with some profound wisdom from [Geek & Poke](http://geek-and-poke.com/geekandpoke/2016/11/27/good-questions):

[image]

Comment: I think one thing that's missing from the conversation is that there are programmers that have to "keep the lights on" with some ancient technology. Q&As about those technologies are very important for them. I'd hate to lose those posts because some programmers are more free to upgrade than others...

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, for sure.  Old contributions should not be lost, merely added to, eg a completely new answer: 'Here is a solution using the latest V2.0 libraries that eliminates the workarounds needed in V1.0'.  No way should the older, tested, verified answers be modified!

Comment: having an answer (partially) backed by Tim Post is an honor :)

Comment: I must say that is a great cartoon

Comment: I am not sure about the details about Reddit. But from what I heard, they calculate the "score" based on the *votes* and the *time*. The older a post is, the less a vote has impact. In theroy this sounds good.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt: Yes, that's called the [Wilson score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem/49787#49787).

Answer (score 2):

The answers should be validated by the process over time.  So if an old answer has 0 votes, it essentially speaks "use at your own risk".  I personally pick the Stack Overflow links out of Google search-results, and sometimes even add Stack Overflow to the search query itself.  Of course, there are other Stack Exchange sites such as "Super User" etc., and those are very valuable too....

I work on a legacy-system, and it is really vital to have the results as mentioned above.

Sometimes it is even valuable to find an unanswered question, just to know that the problem isn't unique to one's own system/set-up and has been experienced by others 'out there'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad for you Alberto that you're working with such up-to-date technology that you're able to feel impatient with those questions and answers from bygone times.  But in the less-rarefied real world one occasionally runs into those bits of antique software still running.  Often the mandate is to find something more modern to replace them, but meanwhile they have to be maintained/tweaked.  Invariably any documentation has been lost, often it was useless to begin with.

So actually the Stack is the best place to find real hints of how to work with that situation.  Asking new questions is pretty much useless because nobody in their right mind works with that old crap any more.  But mining the old questions can really put you on the right path.  That doesn't mean instant answers, but personally I don't come here for those either, and I could care less if others have to work a bit to find their solution too.

Comment: It's not necessarily newer technology, but newer _versions_ of the same technology. For instance, if someone is looking for how to centre some text in HTML, there might be a highly upvoted answer suggesting to use the `<center>` tag*. That answer is blatantly wrong, but because it's highly upvoted and accepted people will start by attempting to follow its advice only to find it doesn't work. *I sincerely hope if an answer such as that existed it would at least have an upvoted comment pointing out how outdated it is :P

Comment: @George M, exactly as Clonkex said, you may look for something as basic as "configure apache2 unix" and find *a lot* of questions and answers. Most of them are really old, so you don't feel safe reading these answers because they may refer and/or explain stuff that is even not anymore safe to implement. The thing is, if you are looking for answers, you don't even know what is safe and what is not, discarding automatically the idea of looking for answers in SO.

Comment: You're speaking for yourself Alberto.  Since it appeared you were soliciting opinions, I gave you mine, based on my experience. If you don't want to use SO, then please don't